# jQuery push is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var phone = [{'Name': 'Example', 'Phone' : []}];
phone[0].Phone.push({'111111111111', '0000000000'});
console.log(phone);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Antone can please help me How can I insert array into phone array?

Comment: Your pushed object is invalid.

Comment: this has nothing at all to do with jQuery - why do you think jQuery library is relevant to your question?

Comment: @JaromandaX Bro I mean push function not working in my code that written in jquery. Please help me How to solve the issue?

Comment: No. It's written in JavaScript. Jquery is just a library of helper functions for JavaScript. I mean you are not even using any jquery in the code you posted. So clearly that is irrelevant

Answer (score 4):

jQuery not required! The main issue is `{'111111111111', '0000000000'}`, it's simply not valid syntax for javascript. You don't need curly brackets for the array push method. Just give it the list of values, like so:

```js
var phone = [{'Name': 'Example', 'Phone' : []}];
phone[0].Phone.push('111111111111', '0000000000');
console.log(phone);
```